# Adding buttons to form made dynamically in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I have created a form dynamically in jQuery. What I want to do is add buttons to the left of the labels in the form (like a column). I have tried append(), insertbefore(), prepend() but they do not provide the results that I require. I have attached an image to give the idea.[There are labels of the form shown and then after the labels are their respective inputs. The buttons are to be place before the labels on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEoio.png). Thanks :)

```
//The form in html:

<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>

// the jQuery to dynamically create input button

var text_input = $('<button/>', {
  text: "Text Input",
  id: 'btn_',
  click: function () {
    var original_form = $('form').last();
    var template = $('form input').first();
    var new_input = template.clone();
    new_input.insertAfter(original_form);
  }
});

$('form').prepend(text_input);  // everything works except this last line where I want this button to be on the left of the input of the form
```

Comment: The methods that you named do exactly what you want to do. All you have to do is use the right CSS for it. There are a lot of tutorials on how to align things in a row

Comment: We don't need the image, show us your code and explain what's wrong with it (AKA [mcve])

Comment: Hi I have updated the question. Please see it :)